# Entity Framework Force CASE-WHEN column to be not nullable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have this custom column in the stored procedure. As you can see, there is no way its value would ever be null:

```
cast(case when ( s.userName is not null and s.Username in ( 'super','superadmin') then 1 
    else 0 end 
    as bit)  as isSuperAdmin
```

But when I map it to Entity Framework, it turns into Nullable:
[image]

Which is okay but I have to do the following, and it is ugly:

```
var isSuperAdmin = (!user.isSuperAdmin.HasValue) ? false: user.isSuperAdmin.Value;
```

is there any way to force it to be a `Boolean` value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server treats the values of most calculated expressions as nullable unless wrapped in `ISNULL`

This should work

```
ISNULL(CASE WHEN s.Username in ( 'super','superadmin') THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) END,0) as isSuperAdmin
```

There is no need for the `s.userName is not null` check. If it matches the `IN` it won't be NULL.